# Sliding Menu with Child Extends Tab Activity in android

Tags: android

How to use sliding menu with child which extends tab activity,i.e., child contains tab layout..  I know how to implement sliding menu but problem is child need to extends both tab activity for tab and base activity for sliding menu.

```
1.BaseActivity for sliding menu:

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
 SharedPreferences pre;
 Editor editor;
 static int dbcount;
 SQLiteDatabase db, db1;
 String url;
 static TextView tv;
 String status, response;

 protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
 protected ListView mDrawerList;
 protected String[] listArray = { "Veg Starters","Veg Burgers", 
  "Non-Veg Starters","Non-Veg Burgers","Veg Wraps","Non-Veg Wraps" };
 protected static int position;
 private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer);

    // Shared pref
    pre = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    // create database if not already exist
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("Mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    // create new table if not already exist
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists pendingdatatbl(Id integer
      primary key autoincrement,Siteid varchar, ToggleStatus 
      varchar, ImagePath varchar,LoginTime varchar,LogoutTime 
      varchar,LatLong varchar)");

    dbcount = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,
          "pendingdatatbl");
    //Database d = new Database();

    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.sidemenu_item, listArray));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            mDrawerList.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.parseColor("#ff5722"));
            openActivity(position);
        }
    });

    // disable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav 
           //drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // orange color of action bar
    android.app.ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new 
           ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff5722")));

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper 
          interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, 
    mDrawerLayout,
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,
    R.string.open_drawer, 
    R.string.close_drawer) 
    {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float 
             slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
            super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);


        isLaunch = false;
        openActivity(0);

    }
  }


protected void openActivity(int position) {

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    BaseActivity.position = position; 

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AndroidTabAndListView.class));
        break;
    case 1:

        startActivity(new Intent(this, tab2.class));

        break;

    case 2:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, tab3.class));
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

        return true;

    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        dialogOnBackPress();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

protected void dialogOnBackPress() {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseActivity.this)
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            BaseActivity.this.finish();

                            Intent intent = new 
                       Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

             }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

 2.Tab Activity class and child class of sliding menu(But here i 
              need extend BaseActivity also) :


public class AndroidTabAndListView extends TabActivity{
// TabSpec Names
  private static final String INBOX_SPEC = "Inbox";
  private static final String OUTBOX_SPEC = "Outbox";
  private static final String PROFILE_SPEC = "Profile";
  static TextView tvNewNotifications;
  @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Inbox Tab
    TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Menu");
    // Tab Icon
    inboxSpec.setIndicator("Menu",
       getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_list_2));
    Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);
    // Tab Content
    inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

    // Outbox Tab
    TabSpec outboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Search");
    outboxSpec.setIndicator("Search",
       getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    Intent outboxIntent = new Intent(this, OutboxActivity.class);
    outboxSpec.setContent(outboxIntent);


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
         getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View chatTab = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_count, null);

    // Profile Tab
    TabSpec profileSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Account");
    profileSpec.setIndicator("Account",
       getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_user));
    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
    profileSpec.setContent(profileIntent);

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); // Adding Inbox tab
    tabHost.addTab(outboxSpec); // Adding Outbox tab
    tabHost.addTab(profileSpec); // Adding Profile tab
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(
        Color.parseColor("#f50057"));

     }

}
```

}

Sliding Menu:

[image: Sliding menu]

Tab menu:

[image: tab]

Comment: You want tabs and sliding menu in the same activity?

Comment: yes..Already in that activity I have tabActivity..

Comment: Please show some effort. what do u have so far?

Comment: I have added my code and the output.. I need to combine those both in single activity.. @Trix